# How to read Mahout generated sequence files in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I am wondering how I can read Mahout generated sequence files in Pig? I guess there might be a UDF but I can't find one yet.

Comment: Have you checked out [mahout support](https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird/blob/master/mahout/src/main/java/com/twitter/elephantbird/pig/mahout/VectorWritableConverter.java) in [elephant-bird](https://github.com/kevinweil/elephant-bird/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using elephant-bird (v2.2.3) like this:

```
register '/usr/share/dse/mahout/mahout-core-0.6-job.jar';
register './elephant-bird-2.2.3.jar';

%declare SEQFILE_LOADER   'com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.SequenceFileLoader';
%declare LONG_CONVERTER   'com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.util.LongWritableConverter';
%declare INT_CONVERTER    'com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.util.IntWritableConverter';
%declare VECTOR_CONVERTER 'com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.mahout.VectorWritableConverter';
%declare TEXT_CONVERTER   'com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.util.TextConverter';

....

sets = LOAD '$INPUT_SETS' USING $SEQFILE_LOADER ( '-c $INT_CONVERTER', '-c $VECTOR_CONVERTER') AS (thing_id:int, recommendations:chararray);

...
```